# any Rest APIs to create a report in powerbi service?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

i have searched official powerbi docs thoroughly.

There are APIs for creating datasets, updating them and for deleting them.
Additionally, there are APIs to clone, update and delete a report.

But after searching a lot, I have not been able to find anything that can help me in creation of a fresh new (visual) report through API?

PS: actually I want to create a visual (not paginated) report without manually going to powerbi desktop or service. I just want to do it with the help of a powerbi rest API.

So is there anyway we can create a new report from existing dataset w/ rest API?

Also, if not possible with rest apis, could this may be possible with powerbi-embedding?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

1. First, you need to generate an embed token for report creation from a dataset present in your PBI Service. It can be done by making a POST request to the API from backend.
2. After that, you can create a new report from that dataset. (Using createReport method in your frontend)

example:

```
let embedCreateConfiguration = {
    tokenType: tokenType,
    accessToken: accessToken,
    embedUrl: embedURL,
    datasetId: datasetId,
    settings: settings, //optional
    theme: theme, // optional
};

// Grab the reference to the div HTML element that will host the report
let embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];

// Create report
let report = powerbi.createReport(embedContainer, embedCreateConfiguration);
```

References:

1. [Create, edit, and save an embedded report | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/create-edit-report-embed-view?tabs=embed-for-your-customers#create-a-new-report)
2. [Embed Token - Reports GenerateTokenForCreateInGroup - REST API (Power BI Power BI REST APIs) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/reports-generate-token-for-create-in-group#generate-an-embed-token-for-report-creation-based-on-a-specified-dataset-example)